# The code dont get result

Tags: arrays, string, laravel

```
            $td_br_resumo = [  
                'setor' => Request('setor'),
                'material' => Request('material'),
                'qtd_sol' => Request('qtd_sol'),
            ];                

            TD_BR_RESUMO::create($td_br_resumo);
```

the output is this:

```
exception:
"Illuminate\Database\QueryException"
file:
"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php"
line:
664
message:
"Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into [td_br_resumo] ([setor], [material], [qtd_sol], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (DA, Garrafas, 4, 2018-05-28 17:56:36.000, 2018-05-28 17:56:36.000))"
trace:
[,…]
```

I already tried in many ways but I did not get a result

Comment: Do other database functions work ok?  Migrations for instance?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have array instead of string in any of your Request variables?